# Mapping NSDictionary from JSON as a result of fetch HTTP request

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession, nsjsonserialization, nsurlsessiondatatask

I have `NSDictionary` object as result of `NSJSONSerialization`, and it has child that is array of dictionary called list. Look at my json result:

```
{
  "tags": [
    "rofl",
    "lmao",
    "funny",
    "haha",
    "lmfao"
  ],
  "result_type": "exact",
  "list": [
    {
      "defid": 3689813,
      "word": "Lol",
      "author": "Lol B",
      "permalink": "http://lol.urbanup.com/3689813",
      "definition": "The name 'Lol' is an abreviated form of the name '[Laurence]'.",
      "example": "\"Hey Lol, you alright?\"\r\n\r\n\"..Well i was chattin to Lol and he said..\"",
      "thumbs_up": 44617,
      "thumbs_down": 9926,
      "current_vote": ""
    },
    ------- bla bla bla ----------

  ],
  "sounds": [
    "http://media.urbandictionary.com/sound/lol-871.mp3",
    ------- bla bla bla ----------
  ]
}
```

I also created a class model for item (child of list).

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Item : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *defid;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *word;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *author;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *permalink;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *definition;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *example;

-(instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;
@end
```

I also created its initializer

```
-(instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.defid = [dict valueForKey:@"defid"];
        self.word = [dict valueForKey:@"word"];
        self.author = [dict valueForKey:@"author"];
        self.permalink = [dict valueForKey:@"permalink"];
        self.definition = [dict valueForKey:@"definition"];
        self.example = [dict valueForKey:@"example"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I already create an array of list item (`NSDictionary`), my problem is I want to map those into my class so I can create an instance of list item. So how to convert item in array into my item class? 
*Should I iterate each item of array and call that initialization? 
or any elegant method for doing that?*

**Additional question**

I am relatively new into iOS development. I just want to parse my request result. Is there any tips for fetch some request and assign its result for datasource a table view (array)? 
This is my fetch method:

```
- (void)fetchDataFromMashape:(NSURL *)URL {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:API_KEY_MASHAPE forHTTPHeaderField:API_MASHAPE_HEADER_1];
    [request setValue:API_ACCEPT forHTTPHeaderField:API_MASHAPE_HEADER_2];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSDictionary *jsonResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"Result: %@", jsonResult);

        _results = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[jsonResult valueForKey:@"list"]];
    }];

    [task resume];
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you use Github's Mantle Framework: https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle. It takes away all the pain from JSON to model serialization and deserialization.

Comment: For some reason, I prefer to use apple's framework right now and try not to use 3rd party library. But thanks for your suggest @ZeMoon

Comment: Side note: The designated method to get a value in a dictionary is `objectForKey:` or key subscripting (`dict[@"key"]`). `valueForKey:` is a key-value coding method with special behavior. Use it only if you really need it.

Comment: Thank you so much, @vadian. I am looking for that.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to create a static method with the json list as a parameter

```
+ (NSArray<Item*>*) parseJson:(NSArray*) json {
       NSMutableArray<Item*>* results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:son.length];
       for (NSDictionary* anItem in json){
              [results append:[[Item alloc] initWithDictionary:anItem]];
       }

       return results;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I got your idea. Thank you!